# Как переключать class в javascript?

Tags: javascript

Я хочу по нажатию на кнопку переключить class у скрытых блоков, проще говоря сделать их видимыми, использовал такой код:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
  btn.onclick = function() {
    var items = document.querySelectorAll('.flex .item');

    items.classList.toggle('active');

  }
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.35s;
}

.active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 660px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
</div>
<button class="btn">Показать</button>
```

Скажите где я ошибся ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Помоту что вы пытаетесь получить доступ ко всем элементам массива сразу, так нельзя.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
  btn.onclick = function() {
    var items = document.querySelectorAll('.flex .item');
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    {
      items[i].classList.toggle('active');
    }
    
  }
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.35s;
}

.active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 660px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
</div>
<button class="btn">Показать</button>
```

Comment: к сожалению плюс не могу сделать , спасибо

Comment: т.е получается надо обязательно проходить по в цикле по элементам ?

Comment: Да, во всех яп.